# Bound on the dimension of the Riemann-Roch space $\mathcal{L}(mH)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose I have a nonsingular curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P^2}(\mathbb{C})$ of degree $n$, and a line $l$ not contained in $C$, given by a linear form $L(x,y,z)$. Define the intersection divisor

$H = \sum_{p \in C \cap l} I_{p} (C,L)p$

Bezout tells us that $\deg H = n$. Now I would like to get the following bound on the Riemann-Roch space $\mathcal{L}(mH)$, with $m$ being a positive integer:

$$
\dim \mathcal{L}(mH) \geq mn - \frac{1}{2} n(n-3)
$$

The first step seems to be to note that, given any homogeneous form $Q(x,y,z)$ of degree $m$,

$$f = \frac{Q(x,y,z)}{(L(x,y,z))^m}$$

defines a meromorphic function on $C$. This I am OK with, but then we're supposed to conclude that

$$(f) + mH \geq 0 $$

This step requires that I know the orders of the poles of $f$, but for some reason I am not completely sure how to do this.

Next there should be some more dimension counting argument of the linear spaces involved, which I am unable to do. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathcal L(mH)$? To me, your last display looks like the definition in the first place, but if you have to show that then I guess not.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for asking. I made an edit to remove the equivalence, which does not help with the question.

Comment: OK, so you need to compute the orders of the poles of $f$; what is the issue here? From what you've written, $f$ has a pole of order $m$ along $l$. I guess you want to show that the intersection multiplicity at each $p \in C \cap l$ is $\ge m$, and that depends on how precisely you are defining intersection multiplicity.